# Format error in python Selenium package

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I'm running on Linux Debian 9 and PyCharmwith web scraping purposes; I'm currently using Python 3.5 as interpreter.

The script is the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import datetime
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
```

Till here, the script works fine, by importing the packages properly; when I try to set the driver by running the following line:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/home/quant/Desktop/DataDownload/venv/bin/geckodriver')
```

I get the following error message, relative to a format problem:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/quant/Desktop/DataDownload/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/home/quant/Desktop/DataDownload/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 76, in start
    stdin=PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 676, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1282, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error
```

Browsing on the web, I found that probably this problem comes out when the executable program has not been unzipped and made executable correctly; to do that, I followed the steps below, by running them on the terminal:

**(1)**.zip file download from the official repository in the github website:

```
wget [here][1]
```

**(2)** unzipped the file:

```
cd /home/quant/Downloads
tar -xvzf geckodriver-v0.21.0-arm7hf.tar.gz
```

**(3)** made the file executable:

```
chmod +x geckodriver
```

**(4)** moved the file on the following path:

```
mv geckodriver /home/quant/PycharmProject/DataDownloads/venv/bin/
```

Could someone help me to understand what's wrong, please?

Thanks in advance all!!

Comment: Not sure about Linux , but in window we do it like this `driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r'D:/Automation/chromedriver.exe')`

Comment: I found that I needed Firefox itself to be installed as well as specifyig the geckodriver pah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `[Errno 8] Exec format error`

This means you are trying to run a version of geckodriver that is compiled for a different architecture... you downloaded the ARM version (`geckodriver-v0.21.0-arm7hf.tar.gz`) and are most likely running on a x86/amd64 machine.

Solution:
go back to the geckodriver releases page and download the correct version for your system: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases.

For example, if you are running 64 bit Linux, you want to download: `geckodriver-v0.21.0-linux64.tar.gz`